# How to dockerize a python web application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask, devops

I am new to DevOps and python. I want to dockerize my python ML model which is a Flask API. I want to know if we only put the .pyd files on the container or the whole source code in the docker container.

Comment: Sorry, but your question sounds like you have never run any python code.

Comment: " I mostly found are keeping their code in the docker container, I am not sure if that is a good practice" thats normal.

Comment: This might be too broad. Are there no tutorials or guides available on the subject?

Comment: Yes I don't work on python. I have read tutorials but what I am asking is that is it okay to put the whole code in the docker container or should I create a single versioned artifact(I don't know how to do this in python,is it same as creating a package)? Some guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Python is not a compiled language. While there are 'tricks' to ship only the bytecode, Python programs are usually shipped with the whole source code

Comment: That answers my query, Thank you Andrea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not a compiled language. While there are 'tricks' to ship only the bytecode, Python programs are usually shipped with the whole source code.